# AWS Lambda Python: Can I load a file from local PC when calling my lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

**Situation:** My AWS Lambda analyze a given file and return cleaned data.

**Input:** path of the file given by the user

**Ouptut:** data dictionnary

Actually in my lambda I:

- save the file from local PC to an s3
- load it from the s3 to my lambda
- analyze the file
- delete it from the s3.

Can I simplify the process by loading in the lambda "cash memory" ?

- load it from local PC to my lambda
- analyze the file

Comment: What do you mean by "cash memory"?

Comment: I mean:    lambda "RAM"  ----- lambda temporary variable storage ----- variables that will disappear at the end of the lambda.

Comment: @Marcin I assume they meant to say "cache".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No we can not directly load the file from local to Lambda or its tmp memory.

But if you want you can use a [Storage gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/?nc=sn&loc=0&whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) which automatically sink any file from a physical drive( your local pc ) into S3. This would help you to eliminate your step 1 ( save the file from local PC to an s3 ).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might use the wrong pattern. Just upload file to S3 using AWS SDK and handle lambda with S3:CreateObject event.

Comment: If you do that, where's the output from Lambda going to go?